# How to find the web root of a hosting in PHP

Tags: php, web-hosting

How to find the **web root** (www, html_public, etc) of a hosting to upload files automatically via the PHP ftp_put() function ?

> The purpose is to propose the installation of a PHP script via a form
>   or the users could send their FTP login.
>
> Then, with a function PHP would upload and install the script remotely
>   on the server. My complete function works perfectly, however I was
>   unable to determine the web directory of the server.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Kind regards

Comment: Is web-root A) `/var/www/` or B) a more specific sub-folder for a single (sub-)domain `/var/www/vhost1/`?

Comment: Root in shared hosting is usually from `/`, so just search for any of `www`, `public_html` etc, in that folder. (Things are different with FTP connections to non-shared hosting however - do you want to cope with that too?)

Comment: The only sure way is to look at the web server configurations. Also, it would help if you specify what kind of server it is and what type of access do you have on it. Do you only have FTP access? Do you have shell access? Is it a linux server running Apache? Otherwise, this question is too vague to answer.

Comment: The purpose is to propose the installation of a PHP script via a form or the users could send their FTP login.
Then, with a function PHP would upload and install the script remotely on the server.
My complete function works perfectly, however I was unable to determine the web directory of the server.

Comment: As halfer says, most shared services do not expose the true path, but in effect chroot to it, so that the document root (or its parent user account is `/`.  However, this is provider-specific so their is not hard and fast rule.

Answer (score 3):

Have you check [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) ?

Try this,

```
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
```

Comment: The question mentions `ftp_put` which implies that PHP is running on the client system, not the server.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do here, but by uploading a file in your webroot with this content:

```
echo dirname(__FILE__);
```

You could receive the full root path on your server.

Comment: The question mentions `ftp_put` which implies that PHP is running on the client system, not the server. Even if it was running on the server, the path to the current file might not even be under the web root.

Comment: I know not or upload it because I don't know in advance the web root hosting.

Comment: @Quentin : Of course, I did not see that when I posted. That makes it a bit harder, but you could try to upload this file to the server and access it? I don't have much experience with this function, and the few times I've worked with it, I've uploaded files to the current server.

Comment: The only way to do it would be to poke around and see if common directories where the web root often appeared exist … which would be somewhat dangerous.